# Why is impurity measure is not a good measure if there are three or more possible classes that the decision tree must distinguish?

Tags: java, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am learning some machine learning and currently learning decision trees.
I am wondering why impurity measure is not a good measure if there are three or more possible classes that the decision tree must distinguish. Is it because of the randomness, something like k-means clustering is better?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The impurity measure for two classes `P(A).P(B)`, where `P(A)` and `P(B)` are both fractions between 0 and 1. As we add more classes, `P(A).P(B).P(C)`, that impurity measures multiplies more fractions together. When you multiply any two fractions you get a number that is smaller than its components. As the number of classes increases, the impurity measure becomes vanishingly small, approaching 0 as classes increase to infinity.

Put simply, the impurity measure loses its meaning with multi-class classification problems, since it becomes too small to function appropriately within a Decision Tree.